# Passing Iterator of a class to another list of class in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, iterator

I tried to make a tree class consists of "Node Structure" which contain a list of pointers for type "Node" and made a "Position class" to act as a dynamic pointer to it and "PositionList" a list of type "Position"

---

I made a list of type "Node" in Node Structure and children function which make a temp positionList and iterate on childList and push iterator into temp positionList

```
class Tree {
    class Position;
    typedef list<Position> PositionList;
protected:
    // Node Structure
    struct Node {
        Elem elem;
        Node* par;
        list<Node> childList;
        Node() : elem(), par(NULL), childList(NULL) {}
    };
public:
    // Position Class
    class Position {
    private:
        Node* node;
    public:
        Position(Node* _node = NULL) :node(_node) {}
        Elem& operator*() { return node->elem; }
        Position parent() const { return node->par; }
        PositionList children() const {
            PositionList posList;
            for (list<Node>::iterator iter = node->childList.begin();iter != node->childList.end(); ++iter) {
                posList.push_back(iter);
            }
        }
}
    };

};
```

this code give an error Message

```
C++ no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list argument types are: (Tree::Node) object type is: Tree::PositionList
```

But when I change the childList list type from Node to Node* and deref the iterator it worked well

```
struct Node {
    list<Node*> childList;
}
...
for (list<Node>::iterator iter = node->childList.begin();iter != node->childList.end(); ++iter) {
    posList.push_back(*iter);
}
```

Comment: Also explain what the actual problem is. "it worked well" for the second example implies there is something wrong with the first. But **what**? Add a [mre] and any incorrect output or compiler errors.

Comment: "I change the childList list type from Node to Node"?

Comment: sorrry for these wrongs, I fixed them

Comment: `iter` is an iterator.If you want to push the element that this iterator points to into the list then you need to dereference the iterator. What is your question actually?

Comment: I think you have made a few copy-and-paste mistake. The error must come from the loop you claim works well, but with `list<Node> childList;`. The loop you say the error message is from can't possibly produce that error message (but it will if you do dereference the iterator).

Comment: `iter` vs `*iter` is similar to the difference between  `_node` and `*_node`.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to post a [mcve]. Make sure the error you report is from the code you post. Asking a question would also help ;)